# Using Rails 3's nested resources to correctly associate models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I am trying to get a better handle on Rail's nested resources, and made a test app with  models **School** and **Class**.  In my `routes.rb` file, I have:

```
resources :schools do
   resources :classes
end
```

With the following models relationship for **School** and **Class**:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible: name
  has_many :classes
end
```

and

```
class Class < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible: name, school_id
  belongs_to :school
end
```

I am having difficulty getting the `school_id` associated with the posts created under an URL like `/schools/1/posts/new`.  More precisely, I would like to define a helper method like `current_school` that could take the first half of the URI where it contains the `school_id`, to allow me to write functions in the controller like `current_school.posts.all` that will automatically pull all the posts associated with `school_id` = what is in the URL.  Thanks!

***Edit**

Here is what I have in `ClassController`:

```
class ClassesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @classes = current_school.classes.all
  end

  def new
    @class = current_school.classes.build
  end

  def create
    @class = current_school.classes.build(params[:post])
    if @class.save
      redirect_to root_path #this will be further modified once I figure out what to do
    else
      redirect_to 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def current_school
    @current_school ||= School.find(params[:school_id])
  end

end
```

And in the `new.html.erb` file:

```
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for([@school, @class]) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :name, "class title" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.submit "Create class", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you nest your resources, you get several helper methods for free as explained [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).  The method you're looking for would be written as one of:

```
new_school_class_path(@school)
new_school_class_path(@school_id)
```

While your classes index page would be:

```
school_classes_path(@school)
school_classes_path(@school_id)
```

In your ClassesController, you would do something like:

```
def index
  @classes = current_school.classes
end

def new
  @class = current_school.classes.build
end

private
def current_school
  @current_school ||= School.find(params[:school_id])
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I added the code, and now the `index` and 'new' functions works fine.  With my `create` function, however, I get an error "Couldn't find School without an ID".  I have posted both my `create` function as well what appears in `new.html.erb` with the `form_for` helper in the question body above, and am not sure what could be causing this trouble.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @daspianist: In your new.html.erb form: `<%= form_for([@school, @class]) do |f| %>` should read `<%= form_for([@current_school, @class]) do |f| %>`

Comment: Thank you - worked great!  Thanks for helping me better understand this.

Comment: One last follow up question about the code `School.find(params[:school_id])`.. given my fledgling understanding of params, I was wondering how this function is working to find the correct school for the `current_school` definition.  Is it from what is shown in the URL `schools/1/classes/2`, and it selectively takes the "1" bit from it since it knows its the `school_id`, or is my understanding incorrect here?  Thanks!

Comment: @daspianist: Yes, that's how it works.  When you define a nested resource, several route mappings are created for you in the general form of `parents/:parent_id/children/...`.  Based on these mappings, a `:parent_id` key is added to the `params` hash with the value that is actually passed in its place.  In your case, the name of the parent resource isn't `parents`, but `schools`.  Based on this naming convention, a similar mapping is created for you.

Comment: Thanks! As a follow up logic, if I had used `Child.find(params[:child_id])` when creating something that  `belongs_to` the `Child` model, and I want to associate it to the `child_id`, would it still be appropriate, given that Child is a nested resource?  I ask because this is exactly the [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14311789/keeps-getting-cannot-find-model-name-without-id-when-writing-new-method/)   Im having now... thanks again for the following up.

Comment: Multiple resources can use the same model in their declaration without causing a problem.  You can make a separate nested resource pair using `children` as the parent resource, and do exactly this.  The index path for that resource would be `child_somethings_path` which would translate to `children/:child_id/somethings`