# Keeps getting "Cannot find Model_name without ID" when writing 'new' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

As background, I currently have three models, `School`, `Course` and `Section`, where they are all in a one-to-many relationships (School `has_many` courses, and Course `has_many` sections, with the corresponding `belongs_to` relationships also established in the model).  I also have the following resources (exclusions to be set later):

```
  resources :schools do
    resources :courses
  end
  resources :sections #not part of the nest
```

Although `sections` could work as part of the nested resources, I kept it out since the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) strongly recommended nests only one layer deep.

So, my trouble is when it comes to creating a new section (In `SectionsController`), and having it linked to the course via the `course_id`

```
  def new
    @course = Course.find(params[:id]) #this line results in an error
    @section = @course.sections.new
  end
```

The first line would always raise an "Couldn't find Course without an ID" error, which I can't get past, despite trying various different combinations of using :id, :course_id, etc.  Since `Course` is a nested resource, is there something else that I'm missing?  Thanks for your help!

When running `rake routes`, here is the output:

```
         sections  GET    /sections(.:format)                            sections#index
                   POST   /sections(.:format)                            sections#create
      new_section  GET    /sections/new(.:format)                        sections#new
     edit_section  GET    /sections/:id/edit(.:format)                   sections#edit
          section  GET    /sections/:id(.:format)                        sections#show
                   PUT    /sections/:id(.:format)                        sections#update
                   DELETE /sections/:id(.:format)                        sections#destroy
    school_courses GET    /schools/:school_id/courses(.:format)          courses#index
                   POST   /schools/:school_id/courses(.:format)          courses#create
 new_school_course GET    /schools/:school_id/courses/new(.:format)      courses#new
edit_school_course GET    /schools/:school_id/courses/:id/edit(.:format) courses#edit
     school_course GET    /schools/:school_id/courses/:id(.:format)      courses#show
                   PUT    /schools/:school_id/courses/:id(.:format)      courses#update
                   DELETE /schools/:school_id/courses/:id(.:format)      courses#destroy
           schools GET    /schools(.:format)                             schools#index
                   POST   /schools(.:format)                             schools#create
        new_school GET    /schools/new(.:format)                         schools#new
       edit_school GET    /schools/:id/edit(.:format)                    schools#edit
            school GET    /schools/:id(.:format)                         schools#show
                   PUT    /schools/:id(.:format)                         schools#update
                   DELETE /schools/:id(.:format)                         schools#destroy
              root        /
```

Comment: Can you please run `rake routes` and add the output to your question?

Answer (score 1):

since your courses are nested with schools, try this

your model should have

```
class School < ActiveRecord::base
  has_many :courses
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::base
  belongs_to :school
end


def new
  school = School.find(params[:school_id])
  @course = school.courses.new
  #your code 
end
```

you can get more idea about this routing by running

```
rake routes
```

HTH

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work (I think you meant to write in the code for `new` for new sections, which was what I was having trouble with, so I changed the code accordingly :)).  Actually I have tried using `params[:course_id]`, but its still giving me the same error of "Couldn't find Course without an ID".

Comment: Hi could u print the params and see what you are getting ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't even get that far.  In the controller I made a dummy variable `@dummy = Course.find(params[:school_id])` just to try to show it, and still get the error that "Cannot find Course without an ID".  If this helps, my "add **new** section" link is placed here: `/schools/1/courses/2`, where it then navigates to `/sections/new`.. is it due to the fact that it has navigated to this new URL that it can't find the id from the params?  If so how do I still manage to pass the information to the new `SectionsController`?  Thanks again!

Comment: place a p params just below the new method and let me know that are the params u get, (you should get a params hash to the controller, unless you have any before_filters set up) :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to have these params in your new section request

```
{:School_id=> some_id, :course_id=>some_id}
```

So that you can get them section binding with course

In section controller

```
 def new
    @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
    @course = @school.courses.where(:id=>params[:course_id]).first
    @section = @course.sections.new
  end
```

hope this will cure :)